# Nested float arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, nested

Python noob here. I need to store an array of float arrays. I am doing this but its not working out:

```
distance = [] ##declare my array
distance.append ([]) ##add an empty array to the array
distance[len(distance)-1].append ([0,1,2,3.5,4.2]) ## store array in array[0]
print distance[0][1] ## this doesnt work, the array above got stored as 1 item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `list.extend` not `list.append`:

The difference between `extend` and `append` is that `append` appends the object passed to it as it is. While `extend` expects that item passed to it to be an iterable(list, tuple,string, etc) and appends it's items to the list.

Using `append` we can append any type of object; i.e iterable or non-iterable.

---

```
>>> lis = [1,2,3]
>>> lis.append(4)      #non-iterable
>>> lis.append('foo')  #iterable
>>> lis
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'foo']
```

---

But `extend` behaves differently and actually appends the individual items from the iterable to the list.

```
>>> lis = [1,2,3]
>>> lis.extend('foo')      #string is an iterable in python
>>> lis
[1, 2, 3, 'f', 'o', 'o']   #extend appends individual characters to the list
>>> lis.extend([7,8,9])    #same thing happend here
>>> lis
[1, 2, 3, 'f', 'o', 'o', 7, 8, 9]
>>> lis.extend(4)          #an integer is an not iterable so you'll get an error
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

---

**Your Code**

```
>>> distance = [[]]
>>> distance[-1].extend ([0,1,2,3.5,4.2])
>>> distance
[[0, 1, 2, 3.5, 4.2]]
```

This returns:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3.5, 4.2]]
```

If you wanted to do this then there's no need to `append` the empty `[]` and then call `list.extend`, just use `list.append` directly:

```
>>> ditance = [] ##declare my array
>>> distance.append([0,1,2,3.5,4.2])
>>> distance
[[0, 1, 2, 3.5, 4.2]]
```

Comment: @fghajhe I've added some more explanation that you might find helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `extend` instead of `append`:

```
distance[-1].extend([0,1,2,3.5,4.2])
```

(Also, note that `distance[len(distance)-1]` can be written `distance[-1]`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this (since you already initialized an empty list to `distance[0]`):

```
distance[len(distance)-1] += [0,1,2,3.5,4.2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you've done:

1. Make a list
2. Add a list to the list
3. Add a list to the list in your list.
   If you've seen Inception, you know that you now have 3 lists, and the 3rd one has some items in it

There are several ways to accomplish your goal:

1.

```
distance[len(distance)-1].extend([0,1,2,3,4,5]) #this one has been addressed elseqhere
```

1. This next one should make the most sense to you. Loop through and append to you inner list

   ```
   for item in [0,1,2,3,4]:
       distance[ -1 ].append( item)
   ```
2. This last one is kind of cool and good to know, though really indirect here:

   ```
   map( lambda item : distance[0].append( item ), [1,2,3,4,5] )
   ```